# C char array always empty. Kernel development

Tags: c, gcc, kernel, ld

I'm coding a 32/64 bit kernel. I'm having a strange issue that when I try to pass a `const char*` , `char *` or `char []`  to a function, the array is always empty.

For example,

I have a `kmain` that do gdt, idt, isrs, irq, video and timer initialization then when I write :

```
 test_func("test");
```

`test_func(char * string)` code for debugging :

```
void test_func(char * string)
{
    if(string[0] == '\0'){
        putch('n');
    }else{
        putch('o');
    }
}
```

I'm always having 'n' on the screen .

and if I test :

```
 if (string == NULL){
       putch('n');
 }else{
       putch('o');
       putch(string[0]);
 }
```

I'm getting `o` without the first char of string

for linking and compiling , I'm using

```
ld -m i386linux -T linker/link.ld  -nostdlib  -o kern.my ../obj/start.o \
                      ../obj/main.o \
                      ../obj/scrn.o \
                       ../obj/gdt.o \
                       ../obj/idt.o \
                      ../obj/isrs.o \
                       ../obj/irq.o \
                     ../obj/timer.o \
                        ../obj/io.o \
                     ../obj/yshell.o \
                        ../obj/kb.o
```

I'm testing out kern.my using Qemu i386

[Linker script]

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
ENTRY(start)
phys = 0x100000;
SECTIONS
{
  .text phys : AT(phys) {
    code = .;
    *(.text)
    *(.rodata)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
  }
  .data : AT(phys + (data - code))
  {
    data = .;
    *(.data)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
  }
  .bss : AT(phys + (bss - code))
  {
    bss = .;
    *(.bss)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
  }
  end = .;
}
```

I used Qemu along with GDB , my info registers :

```
eax            0x1  1
ecx            0x0  0
edx            0x3d5    981
ebx            0x9500   38144
esp            0x104fe0 0x104fe0
ebp            0x0  0x0
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x108000 1081344
eip            0x100356 0x100356
eflags         0x6  [ PF ]
cs             0x8  8
ss             0x10 16
ds             0x10 16
es             0x10 16
fs             0x10 16
gs             0x10 16
```

Comment: Please post the actual code you're working with, and simplify it to the problem you're having.

Comment: Post your linker script.

Comment: I posted the linker script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was on my linker script .

I'm using  ***(.rodata)*** , changing this to **(.rodata*)** fix the issue

rodata is the section where displayable strings are stored in ELF files , the linker assumed it should go to offset 0 while the whole kernel was linked at 0x100000

> GCC places global variables marked as const in a separate section, called .rodata. The .rodata is also used for storing string constants.
>
> Since contents of .rodata section will not be modified, they can be
>   placed in Flash. The linker script has to modified to accomodate this.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it's != NULL makes me feel that you're accessing memory badly somewhere - perhaps with a variable close to the mallocing of the string being passed.

I don't remember how constant strings are stored in the machine code - but I think it's done similarly, just with dynamic, C-managed memory management.

So check to make sure your arrays are never written out of their bounds etc.
Also verify that you get -expected- output when you run the code in a separate file?

Also could you post what test[-1] and test[1] is/evaluates to, and whether or not those are consistent each run?